# NAvigation bar doesn't appear

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I'm developing a `storyboard` app with `UITabBarController`.

I want a `UINavigationBar` on one of the tab `ViewControllers`. I set the property Black `NavigatonBar` in `ViewController` property, and also drag `navigationItem` to this view.

`NavigationBar` is not visible in the `viewVontroller` when I run the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're changing the pop up in the simulated metrics inspector. That inspector allows you to tell Xcode about things that will exist in your app that don't exist in the storyboard.

It sounds like you want to add a navigation controller into the storyboard to wrap one of the view controllers in your tab controller. You can do that in the editor menu by choosing the "Embed in" menu, and then choosing "Navigation Controller".

Choosing that item will insert a new navigation controller, make the selected view controller the root of the navigation controller, and re-route any segues that used to point at the selected to controller to point at the navigation controller instead.